# ContextCompat()' has protected access in 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat

Tags: android-studio

Maybe my code make my question more clear enough.

```
new ContextCompat();
File[] externalFilesDirs = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> icons = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Remove `new ContextCompat();` from your code. Why is it there anyway?

Comment: [Edit] this and make it clear what your question is. Tell us what you want to do, show your [mcve] and show the exact messages or errors or results you get.